# Existing bot is not installed with Teams application

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to implement proactive bot messaging from within Teams application. I also have a bot application registered in Azure Bot Service. Application is up and running. Requests come through well via Web chat and in case if bot has been installed manually in the Teams.

The problem comes when I am trying to create a conversation in the channel once Teams application has been installed. I get the following error in the Teams channel in the Azure Bot Service:

`The bot is not part of the conversation roster.`

However, the app is being installed successfully, but it looks like that the bot, which is declared as a part of it, does not. No bot handler callbacks are being called when app is being installed - therefore I cannot get the conversation reference and service URL to post something.

The app manifest can be found below

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.11",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "cbe06795-8346-405e-841f-12fba7a88d10",
    "packageName": "com.remindApp.main",
    "developer": {
        "name": "RemindApp.Main",
        "websiteUrl": "https://localhost:44302",
        "privacyUrl": "https://localhost:44302/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://localhost:44302/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "RemindApp.Main",
        "full": "RemindApp.Main"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description for RemindApp.Main.",
        "full": "Full description of RemindApp.Main."
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "https://localhost:44302/config",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "c94be2ba-19f9-4dbd-9439-042f435b61e6",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat",
                "personal"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "localhost:44302",
        "localhost",
        "*.botframework.com",
        "*.trafficmanager.net",
        "*.ngrok.io"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "98563d1c-b39c-4958-8e8d-22fa57336a58",
        "resource": "api://localhost/98563d1c-b39c-4958-8e8d-22fa57336a58"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please refer below sample for proactive installation of apps:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-proactive-installation

Comment: You can also reference the samples listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#code-sample) from the BotFramework docs. In addition to the link provided by @Nivedipa-MSFT, there are also samples showing how to **send a simple proactive message** as well as how to **start a conversation in a channel**. Perhaps, if compared to your project, these will show where a potential mistake was made.

Comment: @Vlad - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I was able to receive installation event once, but I can't get the reproducible scenario. I am working on it now, will keep this thread posted.